# How do I use AppleScript with Curl/JavaScript to pull webpage elements and paste to clipboard (w/o 'telling' an App')?

Tags: javascript, curl, applescript

I spend a lot of time in the process of finding information on my company's intranet. Scenario: I'm looking at an email and now need need to find Bob's supervisor on our intranet. Instead of fumbling with a browser, mega menus, clicks etc, I just want to copy Bob's name (or some unique identifier like email address), pop into Quicksilver App which will trigger an AppleScript that will CURL the target page, get the element I want by specifying css/html/xpath/jquery and copy it to my clipboard. Thus, with a few keyboard shortcuts, I don't even have to leave my email and I can hit CMD+V and there is Bob's supervisor. Keep in mind that our intranet and especially our intranet directory is very structured and does not to tend to change. It's not that the info isn't there, it's there, it's just that it takes 5 minutes to dig through from a browser and clicking.

This is different from similar questions because this approach needs to have the following constraints:

1. I'd prefer not to use 'tell' for this (e.g. Safari, Chrome) because I don't want to depend on Apps.
2. I'd prefer not to install other libraries/learn another coding language. I'm open to anything that can be used within AppleScript because I can trigger it to be run conveniently with QuickSilver.
3. Needs to get pass authentication (username/password). The intranet is password protected.
4. Needs to store cookies to get me through to other pages
5. Needs to be able to select elements on page (by CSS/HTML/XPATH/JQUERY)
6. Needs to store results to the clipboard.

**Here is what I have so far:**

> `do shell script "curl -A -HTTPAUTH -CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION --digest --anyauth --location-trusted -v -c /Users/macuser/desktop/cookies.txt --data 'username=myusername&password=password&f_method=LOGIN&url=' https://www.mytestsite.com/login/postLogin.do"`
>
> `set f to execute "javascript document.getElementsByTagName('p');"`
>
> `set clipboard to f`

As an example, I would like to get 'Latest News' copied to my clipboard.

`<p>
<label>Latest News</label>
</p>`

**Steps:**
1. First block sets the variable 'g' to curl my company intranet site, create a cookie on the desktop and login with my credentials. This runs successfully and it spits out the output in the results pane of AppleScript.

**Issues/Questions**
2. Then I try to set f to execute a javascript statement on the results of the curl. I get 'variable f is undefined'. I've dug around and seem to think it's something to do with local vs global variables? How do I fix it?
3. I then try to set the clipboard equal to the stored value of the retrieved element from (4) but because it's undefined, it won't work.
4. Lastly, I want to know how to go to another URL and still utilize the cookie I created. For example, let's say I wanted to go to another site on the same domain that uses Single Sign On. How do I leverage the cookie and pass that info off to that site?

Thanks so much!

Comment: I am not sure where you got the execute line from. But what document are you aiming at. Because the script does not know?. And to tell it you need to tell an app with its own syntax or standard syntax like `do javascript "...`

Comment: Also what type of result are you getting from the Curl apart from a cookie. Because you are not using them. You collect them in the var g. But that is it. You need to parse the result in g. Which is a string

Comment: Hi—Sorry, I have reworked the cURL.  I am getting the full download from the intranet site (obviously what I posted is a mock example). So I can see all the html (about 2700 lines). I just need to be able to extract certain elements and paste it to my clipboard using applescript. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Can you give an example of the elements and the code that surrounds it. (change real names..)

Comment: I have provided an example of the element I'd like to receive…